# Trouble uploading image via paperclip in alternate model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

### Structure

I have an **Image** table which many other tables have foreign keys to. My **TeamMember** table has an `image_id` reference to the images table.

***Image***

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_attached_file :asset

  validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

***TeamMember***

```
class TeamMember < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user

  has_one :image, as: :attachable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :image

  validates :project_id, presence: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :image_id, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum:75 }
  validates :description, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }

  after_initialize :init

  def init
    self.removed = false if self.removed.nil?
  end
end
```

***Controller***

```
def create
  @pteam_member = TeamMember.new(team_member_params)
  @pteam_member.user_id = get_current_user.id

  if @team_member.save
    redirect_to action: :show, id: @team_member.id
  else
    set_project
    render action: :new
  end
end

def team_member_params
  params.require(:team_member).permit(:name, :description, :image, :project_id)
end
```

***View***

```
<%= form_for @team_member, url: team_members_path(params[:project_id]), html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, { class: "form-control" } %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :description %>
        <%= f.text_area :description, { class: "form-control", rows: 6 } %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :image, 'Photo' %>
        <%= f.fields_for :image_attributes do |image_fields| %>
          <%= image_fields.file_field :asset %>
        <% end %>
      </div>

      <div class="actions">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">save <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-saved"></span></button>
        </div>
      </div>
  <% end %>
```

### Problem

No matter what I try, I can't seem to get the `:image` to save as part of the `:team_member`. I get a **ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch** error:

> Image(#70132078464480) expected, got ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile(#70132082679240)

Where am I going wrong? What am I missing, am I approaching this the wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to attach the file to an image object that is associated with the team_member.  What your actually doing is trying to associate the file directly to the team_member as an image association - which is not going to work.  Since you're using nested_attributes, you can fix this just by modifying the request format.  Instead of,

```
<%= f.file_field :image %>
```

Use this:

```
<%= f.fields_for :image_attributes do |image_fields| %>
  <%= image_fields.file_field :asset %>
<% end %>
```

And modify your whitelisted params accordingly.

Comment: I made your changes and unfortunately the image no longer gets posted back.

Comment: @jumpingcode: Can you show what your complete view looked like before this modification?

Comment: I've just posted above, apologies, it does get posted back, but not as part of `team_member`

Comment: @jumpingcode: right, it should be posted as part of `:image_attributes`, which is posted as part of `:team_member`